# Execute subcommand in Scala (script) and let it "take over"

Tags: shell, scala, command-line, process, scala-script

I'd like to create a dummy script (with the prospect of writing a real life script) that invokes for example the Python interactive interpreter from within a Scala process and lets the user fully interact with the subprocess; i.e. the stdin/stdout/stderr of the child process should be connected to those of the parent (Scala) process. I've tried using the following to no avail:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala -savecompiled

import sys.process._

stringToProcess("python").run(BasicIO.standard(connectInput = true)).exitValue
```

however, while it does seem to successfully run a `python` subprocess, the only interaction I get to have with it is `Ctrl-C`:

```
~$ ./scalashelltest.scala
foo

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
```

If press Ctrl-C immediately, I don't even get that output:

```
~$ ./scalashelltest.scala
^C~$
```

Any idea why this is happening and how to make it work as expected?

Comment: Have you tried entering commands into that space? (Perhaps ending with ctrl-d or ctrl-c?) I expect that is the python interpreter operating in piped-stdin mode since you haven't given it a tty.

Comment: Yes: ending with either Ctrl-D or Ctrl-C just exits the whole process; nothing ever gets printed from Python except a Traceback when Ctrl-C is pressed.

Comment: Do processes run that way normally have their output go somewhere? What if that was `echo hello` being run?

Comment: Actually you've just solved the problem: `echo hello` works as expected; adding an `-i` to the python command made everything work as expected.

Comment: If `-i` fixes it then it is likely the tty issue I mentioned. If you want to run a truly interactive program then you need to give it more than just stdin and stdout you need to give it a pseudo-tty.

Comment: thanks, that's a very useful hint; do you have any pointers to how that could be achieved?

Comment: I don't. You'd need to look for scala/java library which can provide one for running programs in it or force the program to not expect one (sort-of what `-i` does for python).

Comment: OK, I'll look at JPty/pty4j at some point; thanks for your help!  I'll accept your answer if you post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't giving python a (pseudo-)tty. You are just giving it stdin (and possibly stdout).

So python is operating in a non-interactive mode.

Running python with the `-i` flag will force it to use prompts even without a tty but the more correct fix is likely to find a scala/java library which can create a (pseudo-)tty and run an application in it.